# How to show estimate ranking in keras?

Tags: keras

> Sorry for exclude whole code, because codes are really huge. I want to get information to solve my questions, like "search for this keyword will help you" or "It can't make".
>
> I'm really Sorry that I don't know correct word such as probability, same meaning in machine learning. So, I will explain very detail as I can.

I know that "Basic machine learning mechanism" is classified with specific weight value, and estimated things by the highest probability. For example, If I input any picture, then program classified with giving weight value, and show result by high estimate probability.(eg: program classified that input data's tag is "cat" by 70% probability, "dog" by 20% probability, and "human" by 1% probability, then show the data's tag is "cat".) Is it right?

So, Based on my knowledge, I make some code using FRCNN algorithm with keras, and training with image_set. After training image_set models with keras, I did test for new image, which test program act "overwrite text on photos and print on console".

The console printed like that ...

```
filename.JPEG    #filename
Elapsed time = 0.7687556743621826    #elapsed time
[('test', 81.2415361404419)]    #[('object tag', 'estimated percentage')]
```

But, I would like to get more information about more estimate probabilities besides the highest one like upper examples...

```
[(first estimate name : 'cat', 70.23232, second estimate name : 'dog', 20.2535, third estimate name : 'human', 1.23532)];
```

I searching to show more information to show more estimate probabilities, and found fc layer(Fully-Connected layer), But it cannot help my question.

Could you give me some keyword to help my question?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking at all, please try to make the actual question clearer.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Sorry, I fix to explain as I can. My codes are maked by many module form, so I don't know how to show Complicated full code. I apologize for can not show my code...

Comment: What makes me confused is that a neural network outputs one probability for each class, so its just a matter of ordering the class probabilities that you should already have. But the output you provide is meaningless without code. Not sure if this question is answerable.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing the output of a softmax layer (kind of), but the results printing are taking the highest probability class only (typically through `np.argmax` or similar). If you just get raw softmax output, you'll get the predicted probabilities of all classes, summing to one, which seems to be your desire